# Different minimum value in QGIS symbology options "singleband pseudocolor" and "Paletted/Unique values"

Tags: qgis, symbology, geotiff-tiff, statistics

I want to color a TIF and manually add the max and min values to the opposite ends of a color gradient. However, different methods give me different min values for the TIF (the max is always 1).

The QGIS Symbology option "Paletted/Unique Values" identifies 0.619 as the minimum.
So does the Google Earth Engine command ee.Reducer.minMax.

[image]
[image]

In contrast, the QGIS Information tab's "STATISTICS_MINIMUM" is 0.667 and so is the minimum value displayed in QGIS Symbology's "Singleband pseudocolor" option.

[image]
[image]

Why do these measures indicate different min values? Which one is correct?

Comment: Pay attention to "STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES". The statistics have been computed with a fast route by using a small sample.

Comment: Good call, thanks! Can I switch this approximation off to see if I can then get the min value of .619?

Comment: Use the tool from Raster - Miscellaneous - Information and check the option "Force computation of the actual min/max values for each band". Run and check if the statistics are updated.

Comment: This gives me this output (excerpt): 
"Min=0.667 Max=1.000  Computed Min/Max=0.619,1.000".

I assume this means that the "real" min is .619 and the one calculated with a subsample is .667, indicating that the symbology option "Singleband pseudocolor" ignores the true minimum? The latter seems problematic to me...

Comment: Do you see the computed statistics now in the layer information? I am not sure if QGIS updates the statistics if the image already has them even just as approximated. What should work for sure is to use gdal_edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html, first with -unsetstats and then with -stats.

Comment: No, it still displays, STATISTICS_MINIMUM = 0.667" but I think I found a solution that does not involve gdal (the latter of which I have never used): Symbology > Singleband pseudocolor > Min / Max Value Settings > make sure "Min / max" is selected (which was the case) AND "Accuracy" is set to "Actual (slower)" (by default, it is set to "Estimate (faster)"). This then also changes "STATISTICS_MINIMUM" to 0.619. Thank you @user30184 for your help that brought me there.